# Why would clang++ fail to compile on a Mac, under Mavericks, except with sudo?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, xcode6

After a most recent software update on my mac, I'm not able to compile and link a c++ hello world program without sudo.

The program (helloworld.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::cout << "hello world\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The invocation:

```
clang++ helloworld.cpp
```

Fails with error:

> ld: can't write output file: a.out for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

But if I do this under sudo,

```
sudo clang++ helloworld.cpp
```

There's no problem.

#### What might be causing this, and how might I be able to resolve this?

---

**EDIT, again**:  The answer turned out not to be working directory permissions, as a couple of people suggested, but the permissions associated with the output file, a.out, of my hello world program.  Credit to Petesh for the solution.

Comment: If there's already a file in the directory called a.out, owned by root, then this is exactly the error you'll get. Try removing that file first (sudo rm a.out) and the command should succeed

Comment: @Petesh: That was actually it, and I feel silly now.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't understand... Why did you accept an answer that did *not* solve the problem???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be sitting in a directory which is not writable by your user.  Look at `pwd` and `ls -ld .` to see where you are and what the permissions are there.  Try also creating an empty file by `touch foo.txt` in the same directory where you ran Clang.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no, touch foo.txt works fine.  Out of desperation, I had already done chmod -R a+rx on my working directory, Xcode.app, as well as all of the include directories I could find.

Comment: @RobLachlan: please show us the output of the commands I mentioned.  Be certain to run them in the very same terminal where you run Clang, with no intervening commands which may alter the environment.

Comment: They're attached.  I have to confess, I'm mystified.

Comment: How about `dtruss -f -t open clang++ helloworld.cpp`?  This should print for you the open syscalls so you can see the path where it fails.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the dtruss utility, that's helpful.  I'm accepting this answer since, it's the closest, and was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely answer is you're running clang++ when your current working directory is not one you have permissions to write to.

Try ensuring that the directory is owned/writeable by you, by running e.g.:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` .
```

(Note, this may not be appropriate depending on *which* directory you're in).

In some cases this happens after a OSX update/upgrade in projects that before was not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but no, it's my desktop.  I did chmod a+rx on it, but no change.

Comment: You need +w as well. +rx means read and execute (for directories, use as CWD).

Answer (score 3):

You probably ran gcc as root (via sudo), and thus the a.out file generated is owned by root.  So just delete it and the problem will go away.

Why did you do that?  Because annoyingly, xcode makes you run it that way to agree to the license agreement!

Comment: Saved me an hour or two.